# What is the practical difference between shared dataset and dataflows?

Tags: powerbi

I'm reading about data flows and the benefit seems to be the ability to pull data from source once and that can be reused by all reports.

My experience is that the same thing can be achieved by making use of a shared dataset.

So what is the practical difference between shared dataset and dataflows?

Answer (score 1):

dataflows are mostly shared datasets. In practice, dataflow is more flexible than dataset. For example I can combine multiple dataflows in a power bi report. The team I work with use dataflow to store common fact and reference tables to drive better reporting standards.

It's also easier to setup access control over dataflows, so we can use it as a data consumption / sharing layer (similar to Views in SQL).

Answer (score 1):

> So what is the practical difference between shared dataset and dataflows?

Dataflows transform and move source data to a Data Lake.  So an easy, self-service way to do the same thing you could otherwise do with Azure Data Factory/Synapse/Databricks and Azure Data Lake Store.

The Dataflows are then available to be consumed by multiple Datasets